# Using Arabic text with custom Font in Cocos2DX

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have a use-case involving Arabic text in a game, with custom font. I am currently using the `createWithTTF` API call, and selecting the Font file that I would need.

However, since Arabic is a Right to Left(RTL) language instead of a Left to Right(LTR) language, the texts are getting printed incorrectly. Apparently, the best solution for this is to use the `createWithSystemFont` API call. However with this call, I would not be able to use a custom font and I would have to resort to a system font.

Is there any way that you guys know in Cocos2DX to use a custom font, with Arabic text? I did look into this [Github issue](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/15321). I tried the [Arabic Writer](https://omar84.com/docs/taw/arabic_writer.html) out, but this gives glitchy output in certain cases. I know that editing the source JSON/Plist file is an option, and I have tried using reversed Arabic strings in the source. However, since Arabic is a language that has combined characters, the result that I get on my UI is not 1:1 with the expected result, and some characters are disjointed(which are supposed to form a special character after getting merged).

Looking for suggestions on how to tackle this. I have looked into almost all open threads related to this, and could not find anything conclusive. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a fix for the Persian language. It works for Arabic as well but you may need some Arabic only characters to it. (Might need some editing)
https://github.com/MohammadFakhreddin/cocos2dx-persian-arabic-support